# How to execute a script from another so that it also sets variables for the caller script

Tags: perl

I reviewed many examples on-line about running another process (either PERL or shell command or a program), but do not find any useful for my needs way.

(As by already received answers I see that my 'request' is not understood, I will try to say it in short, leaving all earlier printed as an example of what I already tried...)

I need:
 - In a caller script set parameters for the second script before call the second script (thus, I could not use the `do script2.pl` s it executed before startin to run the first script)
 - In the second script I need to set some variables that will be used in the caller script (therefore it is not useful to process the second script by `system()` or by `back ticks`);
 - and, as I need to use those variables in the first script, I need come back to the first script after completting the second one
(I hope now it is more clear what I need...)

(Reviewed and not useful the `system()`, `'back ticks'`, `exec()` and `open()`)

I would like to run another PERL-script from a first one, not exiting (as by `exec()`), not catching the `STDOUT` of the called script (as in the `back tick` processing,) but having it printed out, as in initial script (as it is by `system()`) while I do not need the return status (as by `system()`);

- **but, I would like to have the called script to set some variables**, that will be accessible in the calling s  cript (sure, set by the `our @set_var`;)

My attempt (that I am not able to make do what I need) is:

Script1 is something, like:

```
...
 if($condition) 
{  local $0 = 'script2.pl';
    local @ARGV = ('first-arg', 'second_arg');
    do script2.pl;
}
print "set array is: '@set_var'\n";
...
```

The 'script2' would have something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
  print "having input parameters: '@ARGV'\n";
  ... # all script activities
  our @set_var = ($val1, $val2, $val3);
  exit 0;
```

The problem in my code is that the `do ...` command is executed on beginning of the first script run and is not in the place, where it is prepared for it (by setting some `local ..` vars!)

I did try to use the `eval "do script2.pl"`  :
- now it is executed in the proper place, but it is not setting the @set_var into the first script process!

Is there any idea to do it as I would like to have it?
(I understand, that I can rewrite the script2.pl, including whole processing in some function (say, `main()`) and load it by `require()` and execute the function `main()`: that will do everything as I prefer it; but I would like to leave the second script as-is to be executable from shell by itself, as it is now.
 ... and I do not like the way to pass values by a flat file...)

Does anybody have an idea how to do my whim?

Comment: YELLING in the title isn't helping. Could you try and make that more descriptive and a better summary of the actual problem?

Comment: I did not mean 'YELLING', but emphasize the main point of the question! I could do it in more words, but it makes harder to read the header to realize the question itself!
 Is there a way to highlight the words without a capitals in the title?
 Let me know, and i will be glad to make it 'quietly'

Comment: That's what language is for; you shouldn't need visual emphasis.  Also, you may expect readers to also understand what they are reading.  It is enough to state that the calling script should set variables for the caller.

Comment: There, I gave it a shot with the title -- by all means "roll back" if you don't like it (go to "edit" and under a previous revision there is "roll back").

Comment: With all stated conditions you likely have to use `do` and be careful with declarations.

Comment: You're being extremely fussy with your requirements. You've pretty much discounted every way of doing what you ask for, so you need to explain each restriction in some detail.

Comment: *"I did try to use the `eval "do script2.pl"`"* You don't need `eval` there, but **mob's** answer below does work, so you have done something wrong.

Comment: 'zdim' - What do you mean 'be careful with declaration'?
I do not see your point
 Regarding 'That's what language is for; ... you may expect readers to also understand what they are reading':  
 - You are big optimist, expecting people reading carefully everything printed!

Comment: (1) Need to declare things with `our` (so global), which you normally don't do. See mob's answer  2) Visual emphasis substitutes for a suitable use of the language. The text can end up looking like a Christmas tree with all those. It's better to restrain from that and express the emphasis using language facilities (I'm at fault of using visuals too much here!).  Does your title now need very close reading?

Comment: It would probably help to describe what you'd like to accomplish and not what you're trying to do. There's almost certainly a shortcoming in your design that would be better solved a different way.

Comment: 'Matt', 'Borodin'  --  I have added additional description!

Comment: 'zdim' - In my example I reasonably use the 'our' specifier  -  so, I still do not see a reason of your point.   And the 'mod's answer do not accomplish what I need to do: it executed BEFORE first script starts and DO NOT set the parameters, that I in my example set by 'local ..' specifiers!   That is important part of my task:  the second script arguments defined during processing the first script!   Thus, despite of your expectation, even you do not understanding the question! (now ... I did not clear in my question,, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine:

#### script2.pl

```
use strict;
our @set_var = ("foo","bar");
```

#### script1.pl

```
use strict;
our @set_var;
do './script2.pl';
print "@set_var\n";
```

```
$ perl script1.pl
foo bar
```

But it does not if you use:

#### script2.pl

```
use strict;
our @set_var = ("foo","bar");
exit 0;
```

There is only a single perl process in this example, so calling `exit`, even from the second script, exits your program.

---

If you don't want to remove the `exit` call in the second script, we can work around that with some `CORE::GLOBAL` namespace hacking. The gist is to redirect the `exit` function to your own custom function that you can manipulate when the second script runs.

#### script1.pl

```
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = *my_exit };
use strict;
sub my_exit { goto &CORE::exit }
our @set_var;
{
    local *my_exit = sub { warn "Not exiting" };
    do './script2.pl';
}
print "@set_var\n";
```

#### script2.pl

```
use strict;
our @set_var = ("foo","bar");
exit 0;

$ perl script1.pl
Not exiting at script1.pl line 7.
foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks, 'mob' for answer, but it is not resolving the issue!
I need it be executed in place, where I have realized (and set) some values, not on starting (compiling) the first script, as it will be in your example!

Comment: (5 min for editting make reply brocken on two...)
...
 Also, it is no reason, as I understand, in first declaration of the `our @set_var`, as by having it in the second script with `our ..` specifier.
 Good point about the `exit()`: I will do it conditionally. Thanks

Comment: Is it complicated for 'intermediate perl' questions?!  
 I see people do not understand the issues!

Answer (score 0):

(Ok, finally, asked by myself and ansvering by myself, too!)
 ( After additional reviewing, I am realized, that **'mod'** solution does use it, but I did not understand advice!
  I am sorry: my false to step over the real solution!
)

Solution to my question is simple! It is the:

> do EXPR;

That way
 - the second script executed in place where it placed; so, anything defined and set in the first one usefull in the second one;
 - It is printing to STDOUT everything what it should print (the second script;)
 - any variables or objects that are defined in the second script process, are accessible in the first one after coming back; and
 - control is returned to position immediately after the second-script execution with continuation to process the first script commands!

Simple! I am just amazed, why I forget about that 'do...' command. I have used it already not once!

And I am disappointed by that forum much!
 While it is badly designed to display communication, participants, instead of perl-issue reviewing, much concerned on moderating others, teaching them how to leave in such nice forum!

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do exactly, but along these lines it should be very close.

#### test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);

say $0;
system($^X, "sample.pl", @ARGV);
```

```
$ perl test.pl first-arg second-arg
test.pl
sample.pl
$VAR1 = [
          'first-arg',
          'second-arg'
        ];
```

#### sample.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use feature 'say';

say $0;
print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

I used the module [`IPC::System::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm). You can also capture the output of the script (`sample.pl`) through [`IPC::System::Simple::capture`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm#capture()).

**Update:** Maybe you can use [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html). This way you can pass new parameters that you can use from script 2 (sample.pl) to script 1 (test.pl).

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);

say $0;
system($^X, "sample.pl", @ARGV);

my $hashref = retrieve('sample');
print Dumper $hashref;

__END__

$ perl test.pl first-arg second-arg
test.pl
sample.pl
$VAR1 = [
          'first-arg',
          'second-arg'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'arg1' => 'test1',
          'arg2' => 'test2'
        };
```

**sample.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

say $0;
print Dumper \@ARGV;

my %hashArgs = ( arg1 => 'test1',
         arg2 => 'test2', );

store \%hashArgs, 'sample';
```

Comment: Thanks, 'Thanos' for response, but, not, it  not helps!
I need the value of @ARGV be set before calling the second script (and that could be done by your using the 'system()', but IMPORTANT is, that I need some variables be set in the script two and, not just be printed, but be used in the script one!
 That is not possible by using the 'system()' (as I understand).

Comment: Hello again @alex5161, see new update solution. I think this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Again, down vote for the answer. Is there any logic? What the update answer doesn't do what the op asked?

Comment: 'Thanos', thanks for another try.   The 'Storable' is new for me and, at least, this new experience is apreciated already.  But, it is cheating!  :)  The storable saving result in a file, --  I try to have everything be done in the same process space!  ...  It is simple to save result in file and read it from place of calling!!!!     .... It is not a solution.   I agree, using that Storable much simplify that approach - through a file  -  but still out of running process......  Anyway, thanks for familiarizing me with Storable!